# How can restore deleted file and re-push into github?

Tags: github, push, restore

Several days before, i deleted a file :

```
git log
```

Check the log info and get the id to restore

```
git checkout 424a74fba6fbf6ad53e59e7d579427b7acdfde file_name
```

The deleted file restored in my local workspace. I issue command to push after adding some new files, , and want to pull them all(make the restored file in the github also).

```
git add .
git commit -m 'restore deleted file'
git push https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git
! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I git pull according to the notes, then push, but the restored file lost again. How can issue a new push and keep the restored file? Or say the restored file and other new added file push into github together without any error.

Do as geeky01adarsh's suggestion:

```
git checkout  424a74fba6fbf6ad53e59e7d579427b7ab10f8c7    source/os/testing-file-deleted.rst
Updated 1 path from 26e7e5c
git add  .
git pull --rebase origin master 
error: cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
error: please commit or stash them.
git  status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   source/os/testing-file-deleted.rst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to rebase your remote base with the local base by the following command:

```
git pull --rebase origin master 
git push origin master
```

or force pushing may help:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: error: cannot pull with rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.

Comment: commit your local changes first

Comment: @showkey try pushing it with -f